# Heating a city with air conditioning units?

Tags: order-of-magnitude

A couple years ago I have estimated that the heat generated by air conditining units is larger than the heat from the sun.

So I assumed that there is about 1 kW of solar radiation per m². In the urban area of St. Louis, there are 2150000 people on 2392 km². The solar radiation therefore causes 2392 GW.

Assuming that every person has an AC unit and that it consumes 3 kW, this would result in 6450 GW due to AC units, being a multiple of the heat coming from the sun.

The estimates are likely wrong. But it seems that AC units have a rather severe impact on the heat in a city. Wouldn't it make more sense to rather use white painted buildings and other passive cooling techniques instead of using so much AC?

Comment: Yes, but would the passive cooling techniques be as effective? Probably not

Comment: ASU did a study a number of years ago & found that it'd raise nighttime temperatures by ~1 C ([source](https://asunow.asu.edu/content/excess-heat-air-conditioners-causes-higher-nighttime-temperatures))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about the wisdom of using air conditioners not physics